# numpy.array_split doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am running the following code:

```
    sz = np.size(R_cap_i_val) # sz = 1055198
    n_batches = sz // batch_size # batch_size = 32, n_batches = 32974
    R_cap_i_ff_vals = np.array_split(R_cap_i_val, n_batches)
    R_cap_j_ff_vals = np.array_split(R_cap_j_val, n_batches)
    # len(R_cap_i_ff_vals) = 32974
    # len(R_cap_i_ff_vals[0]) = 17
    # len(R_cap_i_ff_vals[1]) = 17
    # len(R_cap_i_ff_vals[2]) = 17
```

I.e. the size of batches appear to be `17` instead of `32`.

Why?

Comment: What is the shape (not size) of `R_cap_i_val`? If it is multidimensional, then [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) only acts on the first axis. Note the `axis=0` default argument in the function definition.

Comment: The default is to split along the first axis.